# Seeking free sdk/lib/framework for UI for OpenLayers app

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, software-recommendations, sdk

I'm looking for free UI lib/sdk/framework to make OpenLayers app that I can have the map in one panel , the layer control in other panel and maybe hovering tool bar (instead of putting buttons on the map).
Bottom line , I'm looking to easily and fast make good looking and practical UI wise app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have guessed this has previously been asked, but there are a couple of these. [GeoExt](http://www.geoext.org/) seems reasonably popular, and is probably a good choice if you have any ExtJS background.

In general, you are probably better off deciding which framework you want, and then typing that name plus "geo" in a search engine. So the top hit for me on "jquery geo" was http://jquerygeo.com/ (where do they get these names!) which I have not tried, but might suit you.